# Goodle Slides: Copy all slides of an existing presentation to a new one

Tags: java, google-slides-api

This might not be a bug but here goes.

The following code reads a presentation and writes the objects back as a new presentation. The problem is that the new presentation is blank! Any ideas as to why that might be?

```
import com.google.api.services.slides.v1.Slides;
import com.google.api.services.slides.v1.model.Page;
import com.google.api.services.slides.v1.model.Presentation;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.List;

public class TestReadWrite extends AbstractGoogleDoc {
  public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    try {
      String title = TestReadWrite.class.getSimpleName();

      // Build a new authorized API client service.
      Slides service = createSlideService(title);

      String presentationId = "1zegq0OWG68l1jgo8qsKsWmL47BBSd3_BXJY53ueEdbg";
      Presentation response = service.presentations().get(presentationId).execute();
      List<Page> pages = response.getSlides();
      System.out.printf("The presentation contains %s slides:\n", pages.size());
      for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); ++i) {
        System.out.printf("- Slide #%s contains %s elements.\n", i + 1, pages.get(i).getPageElements().size());
      }

      response.setPresentationId(null);
      service.presentations().create(response).setFields("presentationId").execute();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(-1);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
The presentation contains 1 slides:
- Slide #1 contains 3 elements.
```